# Positioning an array of objects in OpenGL

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, object

Edit:

I'm still not getting the correct position, all the balls are being drawn at the origin, I think I may be putting things in the wrong places...

Ball.cpp

```
#include "Ball.h"
#include "Vector2f.h"
#include "Vector3f.h"
#include "Glut/glut.h"
#include "GL/gl.h"
#include "GL/glu.h"


Ball::Ball(void)
{
    Vector3f Temp_position;
    position = Temp_position;
    Vector3f Temp_velocity;
    velocity = Temp_velocity;
}


Ball::~Ball(void)
{
}

void Ball::SetPos(Vector3f New_position)
{
    position = New_position;
}


void Ball::Draw()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(position.X(), position.Y(), position.Z());
    glColor3d(1, 0, 0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.3, 50, 50);
    glPopMatrix();
}

void Ball::ArrayPosition()
{

Ball *Yellowball = new Ball[8];
Yellowball[0].SetPos(Vector3f (position.X(), position.Y(), position.Z()));
Yellowball[1].SetPos(Vector3f (position.X(), position.Y(), position.Z()));
Yellowball[2].SetPos(Vector3f (position.X(), position.Y(), position.Z()));
Yellowball[3].SetPos(Vector3f (position.X(), position.Y(), position.Z()));
Yellowball[4].SetPos(Vector3f (position.X(), position.Y(), position.Z()));
Yellowball[5].SetPos(Vector3f (position.X(), position.Y(), position.Z()));
Yellowball[6].SetPos(Vector3f (position.X(), position.Y(), position.Z()));
Yellowball[7].SetPos(Vector3f (position.X(), position.Y(), position.Z()));

}

void Ball::DrawYellow()
{

glPushMatrix();
glColor3f(2,1,0);
glutSolidSphere(0.3, 50, 50);
glPopMatrix();
}

void Ball::SetVel(Vector3f New_velocity)
{
    velocity = New_velocity;
}



Vector3f Ball::GetPos()
{
    Vector3f temp;
    temp = position;
    return temp;
}

Vector3f Ball::GetVel()
{
    Vector3f temp;
    temp = velocity;
    return temp;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
Ball Redball;
float BALL_RED_START = 0;
float RADIUS_OF_BALL = 0.3;
float BALL_RED_END = 8;

Ball Yellowball; 
float BALL_YELLOW_START = 0;

float BALL_YELLOW_END = 8;

init()

Ball *Yellowball = new Ball[8];

for(int i = BALL_YELLOW_START; i < BALL_YELLOW_START; i++)
{

Yellowball[0].SetPos(Vector3f (1,0,0));
Yellowball[1].SetPos(Vector3f (0,0,0));
Yellowball[2].SetPos(Vector3f (0,0,0));
Yellowball[3].SetPos(Vector3f (0,0,0));
Yellowball[4].SetPos(Vector3f (0,0,0));
Yellowball[5].SetPos(Vector3f (0,0,0));
Yellowball[6].SetPos(Vector3f (0,0,0));
Yellowball[7].SetPos(Vector3f (0,0,0));
}

Draw method:

Ball Yellowball[8];

for (int i = BALL_YELLOW_START; i<BALL_YELLOW_END;i++)
{
glColor3f(2,1,0);

Yellowball[i].DrawYellow();

}
glPopMatrix();
```

The result is that is drawing the array at the origin all the balls are in the same place!

Comment: Any reason that you can't put the current x, y, z position (translation) for each in your array?

Comment: thats what I would like! I'm just not sure how!

Comment: For a start, add three lines to your Ball class to store an x,y, and z int value.  Then, you can set these values to some starting value in your program.  In the loop above, use those 3 values in your glTranslate call (e.g. glTranslate( Yellowball[i].x, Yellowball[i].y, Yellowball[i].z ); )

Comment: x,y,z should be private and should be set in the constructor, and then the glTranslate call should be made in the Ball::Draw method. If you want good design at least. See my solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
// first of all, include the x,y position (assuming 2D, since pool) in the Ball object:
class Ball
{
   //...

   private:
      int xpos, ypos;
   //...
};
```

Then when you construct the array of balls, rather than just making 8 balls, you're going to want to allocate the memory on the heap so that it will last throughout your entire game. So do this:

```
Ball *YellowBall[8];
YellowBall[0] = new Ball(x0,y0);
YellowBall[1] = new Ball(x1,y1);
YellowBall[2] = new Ball(x2,y2);
YellowBall[3] = new Ball(x3,y3);
// ...
```

Make sure that when your game is over, you clean up after yourself.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   delete YellowBall[i];
```

Then in your Ball::DrawYellow() do something like this:

```
Ball::DrawYellow() 
{
   glColor3f(/*yellow*/); // Set the color to yellow 
   glTranslatef(-x, -y, 0); // Move to the position of the ball
   // Draw the ball
   glTranslatef(x, y, 0); // Move back to the default position
}
```

It will probably take a tiny bit of tweaking from here, but does this make sense/answer your question?

Comment: I think adding a glPushMatrix/glPopMatrix pair were no bad idea.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense! I will give it a go and see what happens thanks!

Comment: Right still having a few problems I have edited my post with what I have :)